# Почему не работает код?

Tags: массивы, javascript, строки

Почему не работает нижеследуюший код? Никак не могу понять, уже глаза болят, а не могу исправить - в консоли ошибок выдаёт:

> `Ошибка: keyvals[i] is undefined Строка: 10`

```
function reg(param) {
    var keywords = new Array("title", "posX", "posY", "width");
    var keyvals = new Array();
    var keys = new Array();
    var vals = new Array();
    var flag
    var str;
    keyvals = param.split(",");
    for (var i in keywords) {
        keys[i] = keyvals[i].split("=")[0];
        vals[i] = keyvals[i].split("=")[1];
    }
    for (var u in keys) {
        for (var i in keywords) {
            if (keys[u] == keywords[i]) {
                str += (keys[u] + "=>" + vals[u] + "\n");
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            str += (keys[u] + "=>error=>" + vals[u] + "\n");
        }
        flag = false;
    }
    alert(str);
}
reg("title=fe,width=55");
```

Comment: Минусну сразу за `for number in array` :-/

Comment: И яё плохого в for number in array?

Comment: код, откровенно, не очень, и ecли использовать `hasOwnProperty()`, то вашей ошибки можно было бы избежать, но общую картину не улучшить, т.к. вы пытаетесь обратиться к массиву как к хешу, словарю или объекту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в цикле `for(var i in keywords)` используется массив `keywords`, а ключи вы пытаетесь подставить в `keyvals`, по всей видимости, ключи двух массивов не совпадают.

Comment: Спасибо!Чёто я ступил конкретно!Наверно за компом уже долго:)